# MVVM - How can I refer to child ViewModel from parent ViewModel (ViewModels are created in their Views)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I don't know what is the correct way to create a viewmodel relationship if *I use the approach that Views create instances of ViewModel and ViewModel has no reference to View.*

Suppose we have ChildView control that creates an instance of its ViewModel that has SaveCommand.

```cs
<UserControl x:Class="App.ChildView" ...>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ChildViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <!-- some controls -->
</UserControl>

public class ChildViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
    public ChildViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveExecute);
    }
    private void SaveExecute()
    {
         Debug.WriteLine("Child data has been saved.");
    }
}
```

Now, I put two controls in the parent view and want to execute SaveCommand on all children.

```cs
<Window x:Class="App.ParentView" ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ParentViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <local:ChildView x:Name="child1"/>
        <local:ChildView x:Name="child2"/>
        <Button Content="Save All" Command="{Binding ParentSaveCommand}">
    <Grid/>
</Window>

public class ParentViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand ParentSaveCommand { get; set; }
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        ParentSaveCommand = new RelayCommand(ParentSaveExecute);
    }
    private void ParentSaveExecute()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Saving all has started...");

        // <childVM1>.SaveCommand.Execute();
        // <childVM2>.SaveCommand.Execute();

        // From where should I get ChildViewModel?
    }
}
```

**How correctly should I refer to child's ViewModel?**

I found possible solutions:

- Add an interface to the ParentView that returns the child's ViewModel ([like AngelSix did with the password](https://youtu.be/ifTfG_rk4Zg?t=1539))
- Create a class that will be able to bind the ChildView.DataContext to ParentView.DataContext.Child1ViewModel property.

.

*Or maybe it's the wrong approach and ParentViewModel should create a ChildViewModel instances, and than ParentView should set DataContext for child1 and child2 (by binding of course)?*

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the parent view model creating the child view model which the child the child view uses. When the parent vm wants to save, it now has a reference to the child vm and can call save on it too.

Comment: The child view models should inherit the `DataContext` from the parent instead of creating their own view models.

Comment: @mm8 Do you have any links to examples of how should I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like RTF mentioned, for these types of operations it is generally an easier approach to have the parent VM create the children VMs so that the parent can maintain a reference to the children VMs. However, you can definitely do what you want without architectural changes.

In the view:

```
 <Button
  Content="Save All"
  Height="37" Command="{Binding SaveAllCommand}">
       <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PassThroughConverter }">
                  <Binding Path=“DataContext” ElementName="child1"/>
                  <Binding Path=“DataContext” ElementName="child2"/>
            </MultiBinding>
       </Button.CommandParameter>
 </Button>
```

The Converter:

```
public class PassThroughConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values.ToList();
        }
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

In parent view model:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand<object> ParentSaveCommand { get; set; }
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        this.ParentSaveCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(obj => this.ParentSaveExecute(obj));
    }
    private void ParentSaveExecute(object items)
    {
        foreach (var item in (ChildViewModel[])items)
        {
            item.SaveCommand.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I forgot about multi binding. You have a small mistake in MultiBinding, DataContext is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly always assign DataContext in code behind so I can inject dependencies to view model constructor. My approach is to pass parent view model to child view models via constructor. In the case you have I would create a SaveAll event in parent view model and have child view models subscribe to it.

Edit: I don't use any framework for what I mentioned.
To give you a general idea on how I would handle SaveAll in Child view models -

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Child1ViewModel = new Child1ViewModel(this); // inject parent view model to child view model
        //Child2ViewModel = new Child2ViewModel(this);
    }

    public event SaveAllEventHandler SaveAll; // Child view models can subscribe to this event

    // ...
}


public class Child1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Child1ViewModel(MainViewModel parentViewModel)
    {
        parentViewModel.SaveAll += OnSaveAll;
    }

    private void OnSaveAll(object sender, SaveAllEventArgs e)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I hope that clarifies it a bit :)

Edit2: Like I had mentioned in my original response, for this to work you would need to set the DataContexts in MainWindow's constructor in code behind (and not in xaml).

Comment: I have added a code snippet to give you a general idea on what I meant.

Comment: OK, I know what you mean. But you have a problem when a parent wants to remove a child. The parent must order the child to unsubscribe itself from SaveAll or... OnSaveAll should be add to SaveAll handler as a weak event.

Comment: Yes. I generally use weak event for this. I didn't use in this code for the sake of demonstration. Thanks :)